# how to create a folder in /system with root in my app

Tags: android, directory, root, explorer, su

Hi in my Filemanager i want to add an Option to create Folder in /system directory. Ive tried this to add to my code. It doesnt work. What did I wrong?

```
File dir = new File(path + name);

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \"mount -orw,remount /\"");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \"mkdir" + dir.getAbsolutePath + "\"");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed! I need to add a space after mkdir.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \"mkdir " + dir.getAbsolutePath + "\"");
```